# Angular FormGroup's FormField not definded exception

Tags: angular

I have created a FormGroup, the problem is the title, gender is Object and the objects have other properties also like **createdBy, status** with defined id and code.

```
 this.vendorForm = new FormGroup({
            firstName: new FormControl(''),
            lastName: new FormControl(''),
            title: new FormGroup({
                id: new FormControl(''),
                code: new FormControl('')
            }),
            gender: new FormGroup({
                id: new FormControl(''),
                code: new FormControl('')
            })
        });
```

When I tried to select the object and setting to the FormGroup `ERROR Error: Cannot find form control with name: createdBy.` exception is throwing.
Is there any way to solve this issue. I want to set the object's properties automatically.

Comment: there is no `createdBy` in your controls list, so no wonder you have that error.

Comment: Yah I got that, is there any way to ignore createdBy?

Comment: Could you also post the code of your HTML template? From what I see so far the error looks to me as if there is a FormControl named "createdBy" in the HTML template but not in your code

Comment: No, there is no createdBy in html. title and gender is dropdown value with objects.

Comment: Ok, but in your code title and gender are FormGroups, not FormControls. Shouldn't a dropdown be a FormControl?

Comment: Obviously there IS a reference to `createdBy` in your HTML